# installing `lightdm` in Dockerfile raises interactive keyboard layout menu

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, interactive, apt-get

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
# Pull from CentOS RPM Build Image
FROM ubuntu

# Update the image
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install lightdm -y
```

The problem I have is when I'm building this container with `docker build -t dumbcontainer .`, at some point I get an interactive menu for choosing a keyboard layout:

```
Adding system user `lightdm' (UID 106) ...
Adding new user `lightdm' (UID 106) with group `lightdm' ...
Creating home directory `/var/lib/lightdm' ...
usermod: no changes
usermod: no changes
usermod: no changes
Adding group `nopasswdlogin' (GID 109) ...
Done.
Setting up libnih-dbus1:amd64 (1.0.3-4.3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mountall (2.54ubuntu1) ...
Setting up perl-modules-5.22 (5.22.1-9) ...
Setting up libperl5.22:amd64 (5.22.1-9) ...
Setting up perl (5.22.1-9) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/prename to provide /usr/bin/rename (rename) in auto mode
Setting up libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.11-7ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.11-7ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libpython-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.11-1) ...
Setting up python (2.7.11-1) ...
Setting up libtalloc2:amd64 (2.1.5-2) ...
Setting up libtevent0:amd64 (0.9.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libroken18-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libasn1-8-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libhcrypto4-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libheimbase1-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libwind0-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libhx509-5-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libkrb5-26-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libheimntlm0-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libgssapi3-heimdal:amd64 (1.7~git20150920+dfsg-4ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsasl2-modules-db:amd64 (2.1.26.dfsg1-14build1) ...
Setting up libsasl2-2:amd64 (2.1.26.dfsg1-14build1) ...
Setting up libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up libtdb1:amd64 (1.3.8-2) ...
Setting up libldb1:amd64 (2:1.1.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.11-7ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-talloc (2.1.5-2) ...
Setting up samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Setting up libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.3.9+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Setting up libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:amd64 (0~git20131104-1.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtxc_dxtn_s2tc.so.0 to provide /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtxc_dxtn.so (libtxc-dxtn-x86_64-linux-gnu) in auto mode
Setting up bzip2 (1.0.6-8) ...
Setting up distro-info-data (0.28ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up eject (2.1.5+deb1+cvs20081104-13.1) ...
Setting up libmagic1:amd64 (1:5.25-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up file (1:5.25-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up iproute2 (4.3.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up ifupdown (0.8.10ubuntu1) ...
Creating /etc/network/interfaces.
Setting up libisc-export160 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libdns-export162 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1) ...
Setting up isc-dhcp-client (4.3.3-5ubuntu12) ...
Setting up isc-dhcp-common (4.3.3-5ubuntu12) ...
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.108ubuntu15) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Configuring keyboard-configuration
----------------------------------

The layout of keyboards varies per country, with some countries having multiple
common layouts. Please select the country of origin for the keyboard of this
computer.

  1. Afghani                                     48. Irish
  2. Albanian                                    49. Italian
  3. Amharic                                     50. Japanese
  4. Arabic                                      51. Japanese (PC-98xx Series)
  5. Arabic (Morocco)                            52. Kazakh
  ........
```

I try putting an option, but the process just stalls at that point

Is there any way that I can choose an option interactively, or have docker pass an option when asked to do so?

Comment: Running GUI applications within Docker, let alone an entire window manager, is ... non-trivial. I wouldn't recommend treating Docker as a lightweight VM.

Comment: @lurscher could you find a solution for this?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/876240/how-to-automate-setting-up-of-keyboard-configuration-package

Answer (score 53):

This should work:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install lightdm -y
```

I had the same problem installing CUDA and this fixed it.

Comment: Thank you!! I was only trying to install an X server in a Dockerfile, but the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` did the trick just as well!

Comment: @arhuaco Hi, can you please share your Dockerfile for installing CUDA?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/WillNilges/bf6c47e7e7924f541b4bd70b8e74a6b2

FWIW, here's mine.

Answer (score 18):

1. copy a working /etc/default/keyboard file to the directory that contains the Dockerfile
2. Add the following line to your Dockerfile before installing xdm or lightdm

   COPY ./keyboard /etc/default/keyboard

Example keyboard file:

```
# Check /usr/share/doc/keyboard-configuration/README.Debian for
# documentation on what to do after having modified this file.

# The following variables describe your keyboard and can have the same
# values as the XkbModel, XkbLayout, XkbVariant and XkbOptions options
# in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="intl"
XKBOPTIONS=""

# If you don't want to use the XKB layout on the console, you can
# specify an alternative keymap.  Make sure it will be accessible
# before /usr is mounted.
# KMAP=/etc/console-setup/defkeymap.kmap.gz
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Comment: Had the same problem...these steps didn't work for me.
Stuck with the same interactive menu.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

`ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

directly in Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a TERM environment variable before running the install:
`ENV TERM xterm`
in order to get rid of that error, although I'm not sure how you would specify the keyboard option.

Comment: FYI - this does work (setting the TERM env) if you don't mind the interactive prompt (which you seem to be ok with). If you want something completely auto, you would need to see how to spec the keyboard option some other way. But also what @bmitch said. Vagrant or similar may be a better option.