# How to create a non interactive ENV to prevent the CUDA question:"Country of origin for the keyboard"

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to install `CUDA` using a Dockerfile. However, the installation keeps getting stuck, when user input is demanded: `Country of origin for the keyboard`

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43290817/11628437) SO post to prevent it by doing -

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

However, it did not work.

Here is my Dockerfile -

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

WORKDIR /app
RUN echo "Hello World!"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libosmesa6-dev \
    sudo \
    wget \
    curl \
    unzip \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    &&  apt-get install \
    libosmesa6-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin \
    && sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2204.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600 \
    && wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.2.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local_12.2.0-535.54.03-1_amd64.deb \
    && sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local_12.2.0-535.54.03-1_amd64.deb \
    && sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/ \
    && sudo apt-get update
RUN sudo apt-get -y install cuda \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf cuda-ubuntu2204.pin \
    && rm -rf cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-2-local_12.2.0-535.54.03-1_amd64.deb
```

I also tried `RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo apt-get -y install cuda` but to no avail.

This is how I build my Docker image - `docker build -t tbd_jax:latest .`

Comment: Does it work better if you remove every last mention of `sudo` in this file?  You don't need `sudo` because you're already root (or you can easily specify `USER root`); it tends to not work well since there aren't passwords and there's no way to enter them in the Docker environment; and since `sudo` resets the environment, the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` environment variable is lost.

Comment: It does. I didn't realize `sudo` reset the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't usually need `sudo` in Docker at all.  You can delete every instance of `sudo` in the Dockerfile: don't install it, just run *e.g.* `apt-get install` without `sudo` first, and so on.

One of `sudo`'s behaviors is to reset the environment to a set of known minimum environment variables.  You can demonstrate this even without Docker: if you run

```bash
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive sudo env
```

then the environment that `env` sees won't have the environment variable you set "outside" of `sudo`.  Because of this, APT isn't seeing that environment variable when it runs, and it's doing its normal interactive prompting.

In practice a Docker container isn't a multi-user environment, and you can just become root if you need to be.  In a Dockerfile, you can explicitly run `USER root` to switch to a root user (this is often the default in any case); or you can `docker run -u root ...` a container's main process as root.  There's no reason to install or configure `sudo`.